# PowerShell sort of array of array of integers does not work

Tags: powershell, sorting, sort-object

I would like to sort an array of arrays of integers. And yes, I expect the sort function to sort first based on the first integer, then the second, and so on.

So for this array of array of ints:

```
((99,42),(100,42))
```

I would expect the first element `(99,42)` to be before the second element `(100,42)`

Here is the naive solution:

```
$array_of_array | Sort-Object {$_}| foreach {Write-Output ("<"+$_+">")}
```

Much to my surprise this does not work:

```
((99,42),(100,42))| Sort-Object {$_}|foreach {Write-Output ("<"+$_+">")}

  <100 42>
  <99 42>
```

I debugged this and it seems I get a string comparison rather than an int comparison of each element.  `"100"<"99"`, but `100 > 99`.

Here is a hack:

```
((99,42),(100,42))| Sort-Object {$_|foreach {($_+65)}}|foreach {Write-Output ("<"+$_+">")}
<99 42>
<100 42>
```

But why does this go wrong and how would I do this the right way?

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to use 2 expressions: `((101,43),(101,42),(99,42),(100,42)) | Sort-Object { $_[0] }, { $_[1] } | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }`. A Tuple would also work `((101,43),(101,42),(99,42),(100,42)) | Sort-Object { [Tuple]::Create($_[0], $_[1]) } | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }`

Answer (score 3):

- Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell 7.2.x, *arrays* do not sort meaningfully *as-is*, unless they happen to be composed of *strings only***.
- The reason is that `[array]` instances are in effect compared by their PowerShell-specific *stringification*, which is the space-concatenated list of their stringified elements.

**Workaround for `[int[]]` arrays of *arbitrary length***:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
# -> '<100 42>', '<99 42>' - note the -Descending
(99, 42), (100, 42) | 
  Sort-Object -Descending { $_.ForEach({ '{0,11}' -f $_ }) } | 
  ForEach-Object { "<$_>" }
```

The above converts each number in each input array to a left-space-padded string of fixed length (based on the max. length of an `[int]` value expressed as a string<sup>[2]</sup>), which in effect converts each input array to a *string* array whose *lexical* sorting then equals how *numerical* sorting would work based on the original array's elements, based on PowerShell's array stringification.

**Workaround for arrays of *up to 8 elements***:

Array-*like* types that (also) implement the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) interface, such as *tuples* ([`System.Tuple`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Tuple)) and *value tuples* ([`System.ValueTuple`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ValueTuple)), *are* compared via that interface by `Sort-Object`. This is what the workaround that [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests in his comment on the question relies on; while there is a way not to have to enumerate the array elements *one by one*, the workaround is limited to arrays with *at most 8 elements*, based on the constructor overloads available:

```
# Works for arrays of up to 8 elements.
# -> '<1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10>', '<1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9>'
(1..7 + 9), (1..7 + 10) | 
  Sort-Object -Descending { [ValueTuple]::Create.Invoke($_) } | 
  ForEach-Object { "<$_>" }
```

---

**Potential future improvement:**

As of PowerShell 7.2.x, only input objects that implement the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) interface are compared via that interface, (unfortunately) not also *collection* objects that (only) implement the [`System.Collections.IStructuralComparable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IStructuralComparable) interface, such as .NET *arrays* (although many other array-*like* collection types do *not*).

[GitHub issue #18389](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18389) requests that [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) honor input objects whose types implement (only) `System.Collections.IStructuralComparable` too.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, a PowerShell array literal such as `99, 42` is an `[object[]]` array whose elements happen to be `[int]` instances. Similarly, the collection type that the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) emits is an array-*like* collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, but in terms of PowerShell *stringification* it behaves the same as an array.</sup>

<sup>[2] Verify with `"$([int]::MinValue)".Length`, which yields `11`. See also: `-f`, the [format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)</sup>